# Properties about $f(n)$ that sums all positive integers that are coprime to $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $f(n)$ be the function that sums all positive integers that are coprime to $n$. For example, if we take $n=6$, $f(6)=1+5=6$ because $\gcd(1,6)=\gcd(5,6)=1$.

The formula for $f(n)$ is given as $f(n)=n\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$, where $\phi(n)$ denotes the Euler phi function. By this formula and the multiplicativity of $\phi(n)$, we say $f(nm)=2f(n)f(m)$.

My question is, is there a way to obtain $f(nm)=2f(n)f(m)$ without applying $f(n)$'s formula?

Comment: Note that it is critical to specify $\gcd(n,m)=1$ when citing the multiplicativity of $\varphi$.

Comment: As to your question, you could, of course, reproduce the proof that $\varphi$ is multiplicative, suitably modified for $f$.  Shouldn't be at all harder.  Might be a useful exercise in understanding that proof.

Comment: Technically the sum must be restricted to those positive integers which are at most $n.$ [Otherwise sum infinite] But it could be argued most would assume that.

Comment: $f(mn)=f(n)m+n\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ by playing.

Comment: It is fair to ask:  What is the underlying motivation for your question, @Mr.Infinity?